# T-SQL query to count users grouping per last 4 completed quarters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I currently have the following query:

```
SELECT datename(Year,Date) + '-Q' + datename(Quarter,Date) as Trimester,
    COUNT(Distinct(Users.user_id)) Users,
    COUNT(Orders.Source) Orders,
    COUNT(Distinct(Users.item_id)) Items
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Users] 
INNER JOIN Dim_Date ON Users.date_id=Dim_Date.date_id 
WHERE Orders.[Table] LIKE '%expr1%' or Orders.[Table] LIKE '%expr2%'
GROUP BY 
    datename(Year,Date) + '-Q' + datename(Quarter,Date)
```

This gets a table with Columns Trimester, Users, Datasheets and Projects, and I get the trimesters (quarters) and grouped data. For example:

| Trimester | Users | Orders | Items |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-Q2 | 50 | 50 | 50 |
| 2022-Q3 | 60 | 60 | 60 |

What I'd like to have now is grouping not just by a single quarter, but by the 4 last completed quarters, and get the sum of users, orders and items. For example, for dates such as 5th-Jan-2024 the grouping should take the last 4 completed quarters, i.e. from Q1-23 to Q4-23

| Trimester | Users | Orders | Items |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q422-Q323 | 800 | 800 | 800 |
| Q123-Q423 | 900 | 1000 | 1000 |

Is there a way to achieve that with a T-SQL query using Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Please provide table schema and sample data that generates your example output and desired output

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your `where` clause.

Remove the data from the current quarter like this:

```
where datename(Quarter,Date) <> datename(Quarter,getdate())
```

Then add a condition to remove everything that is older than 4 quarters + the time passed in the current one:

```
and Date > DATEADD(qq, 4, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, Date), 0))
```

`DATEDIFF(qq, 0, Date)` --> Quarters since time began.

`DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, Date), 0)` --> Start of current quarter.

`DATEADD(qq, 4, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, Date), 0))` --> 4 quarters before now + the time that passed since beginning of current quarter.

If you count what remains under these conditions your get the numbers you need.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want to do a rolling summation over four quarters. This approach will work if there aren't any gaps. It will also sort of handle the initial three rows where there is no look-back data by annotating the range. Some of the formatting is a bit of a hack which of course you can adjust to preference. `format()` doesn't have an option for quarter number though. You'll probably want to further consider how you want to handle/display those periods:

```
with data as (
    SELECT
        datepart(year, "Date") as yr, datepart(quarter, "Date") as qtr,
        concat('Q', datepart(quarter, "Date",
            right(concat('00', datepart(year, "Date") % 100), 2)) as q,
        COUNT(Distinct Users.user_id) Users,
        COUNT(Orders.Source) Orders,
        COUNT(Distinct Users.item_id) Items
    FROM [DB].[dbo].[Users] 
        INNER JOIN Dim_Date ON Users.date_id = Dim_Date.date_id 
    WHERE Orders.[Table] LIKE '%expr1%' or Orders.[Table] LIKE '%expr2%'
    GROUP BY datepart(year, "Date"), datepart(Quarter, "Date")
), rolling as (
    select *,
        coalesce(lag(q, 3) over (order by yr, qtr) + '-', min(q) over () + '*') as q0,
        sum(Users)  over (order by yr, qtr rows between 3 preceding and current row) as RollingUsers,
        sum(Orders) over (order by yr, qtr rows between 3 preceding and current row) as RollingOrders,
        sum(Items)  over (order by yr, qtr rows between 3 preceding and current row) as RollingItems
    from data
)
select 
    q as CurrentQtr, Users, Orders, Items,
    concat(q0, q) as "RollingFourQtr", RollingUsers, RollingOrders, RollingItems
from rolling
order by yr, qtr;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/XTgJlbgO

For the case where whole quarters could in fact be missing (which I doubt is possible) you'd probably use a left join from the date dimension instead. See a possible way to handle this by a different approach here where it numbers the quarters and uses a cross apply look-up instead:

https://dbfiddle.uk/9qCnXpar